# ngfor routerlink browser back button error Angular2/4

Tags: angular, ngfor, routerlink

I have an Angular App with a ngFor retrieving values from a firestore collection then placed inside a [routerLink] to navigating to a list page

In class.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div *ngFor="let folder of folders" class="col-3">
    <a [routerLink]="[`/class/board/${folder?.folder}`]">
      <div class="folder">
        <h6>{{folder?.folder}}</h6>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page navigates to its target as it should. The problem persist when the browsers back button is used. After navigating from **class.component.html** to **classlist.component.html**,  if I press the browsers back button to navigate back to class.component.html, all elements of the ngFor do not render. If I hit refresh all  elements of the ngFor return/show.

classlist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

export class ClasslistComponent implements OnInit {
folder:any;

  constructor(private urlId:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.folder = urlId.snapshot.params['folder'];
  }
```

classlist.component.html

```
<p>{{folder}}<p> //<-- outputs "drywall"
```

It correctly outputs the ActivatedRoute snapshot "folder" from the URL but when I click the browser back button going back to **class.component.html** all the  DOM elements are gone. I have to reload the page for everything to return

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import {RouterModule, ActivatedRoute, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path:'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent},
{path:'guestlist', component:GuestComponent},
{path:'login', component:LoginComponent},
{path:'settings', component:SettingsComponent},
{path:'chat/:chatId', component:ChatsComponent},
{path:'taskmanager', component:TodoComponent},
{path:'class/board/:folder', component:ClasslistComponent},
{path:'class', component:ClassComponent},
{path:'', component:HomeComponent},
{path:'**', component:ErrorComponent}
]

BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'charting'),
HttpModule,
HttpClientModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
AngularFirestoreModule,
AngularFireAuthModule,
AngularFireStorageModule,
FormsModule,
FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
FacebookModule.forRoot()
```

If I directly use href instead of routerLink I have no issues using browser back button. All ngFor elements render on 1st loading without having to refresh.

this href works

```
<a href="/class/board/{{folder?.folder}}">
```

instead doesnt

```
<a [routerLink]="['/class/board/'+folder?.folder]">
```

also if I use routerlink directly from a doc it works as well

```
<a [routerLink]="['/class/board/'+listitem?.item]">
```

it seems the only time the issue persist is when **[routerLink]** is used inside an **ngFor** when retrieving data from a **collection**

Ive looked all over for a solution. Is there a solution to this or where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Without your code, we can't do anything.

Comment: The given code is insufficient to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ive updated code

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same problem. Did you ever figure it out?